# How to marshal a byte/uint8 array as json array in Go?

Tags: json, go

I've got a struct with a `[]uint8` member and I'm writing it with `json.Marshal`. Trouble is, it's interpreting the `uint8`s as `char`s and it outputs a string rather than an array of numbers.

I can get this to work if it's a `[]int`, but I don't want to have to allocate and copy over the items if I can avoid it. Can I?

Comment: As I said in the question, I am using `json.Marshal`. My question is not about `fmt`, it's about the `json` library.

Comment: (I did have a comment asking about how I was outputting it, the author deleted it after I answered. Might as well keep my response.)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal), a `[]byte` will be encoded as a Base64 string.

> *"Array and slice values encode as JSON arrays, **except that []byte encodes as a base64-encoded string**, and a nil slice encodes as the null JSON object."*

So I think that you may need to make your struct implement the [Marshaler](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshaler) interface by implementing your own `MarshalJSON` method that makes a more desirable JSON array encoding out of your `[]uint8`.

Take this example:

```
import "fmt"
import "encoding/json"
import "strings"

type Test struct {
    Name  string
    Array []uint8
}

func (t *Test) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    var array string
    if t.Array == nil {
        array = "null"
    } else {
        array = strings.Join(strings.Fields(fmt.Sprintf("%d", t.Array)), ",")
    }
    jsonResult := fmt.Sprintf(`{"Name":%q,"Array":%s}`, t.Name, array)
    return []byte(jsonResult), nil
}

func main() {
    t := &Test{"Go", []uint8{'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'}}

    m, err := json.Marshal(t)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s", m) // {"Name":"Go","Array":[104,101,108,108,111]}
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/Tip59Z9gqs

---

Or maybe a better idea would be to make a new type that has `[]uint8` as its underlying type, make that type a `Marshaler`, and use that type in your struct.

```
import "fmt"
import "encoding/json"
import "strings"

type JSONableSlice []uint8

func (u JSONableSlice) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    var result string
    if u == nil {
        result = "null"
    } else {
        result = strings.Join(strings.Fields(fmt.Sprintf("%d", u)), ",")
    }
    return []byte(result), nil
}

type Test struct {
    Name  string
    Array JSONableSlice
}

func main() {
    t := &Test{"Go", []uint8{'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'}}

    m, err := json.Marshal(t)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s", m) // {"Name":"Go","Array":[104,101,108,108,111]}
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/6aURXw8P5d

Comment: Brilliant. I think the second option is a bit more future-proof. Thanks very much.

Comment: @Joe: You're welcome. And I updated to make it a little more complete by handling a `nil` slice as `null`.

Comment: But the program isn't printing the alphabets correctly?