# Struct / Array format append to JSON file

Tags: go

I have a array/struct that constantly printing

```
for{
        results, errz := client.ReadHoldingRegisters(0, 3)
        if errz != nil {
            fmt.Printf("%v\n", errz)
        }

        fmt.Printf("results %v\n", results)
    }
```

Printing output will be like this.

```
[0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

How do i add it into append it into json format? I'm very new to GOLANG.
I printed the type out

```
fmt.Printf("var1 = %T\n", results)
```

Results is   []uint8
I need save as int on json format.

Comment: when you mean json, would turning [0 0 0 0 0 0] into [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] be enough for you?

Comment: Yes. that will be suffice. Thank you.

Comment: @brunoff 
Something like this

{
  "data": {
    "1": "0,0,0,0,0,0"
  }
}

Comment: j := fmt.Sprintf("%#v",*results); j = "{ \"data\": { \"1\": \""+j[7:len(j)-1]+"\"} }" // j will hold your json in the format you commented right now. too simple and without error checking, but at least works for this simple situation

Comment: I added your two lines just after printf results.
and got this error 
invalid indirect of results (type []byte)

Comment: Oops, nevermind i added amplesand & for the results instead of pointer *.

Comment: What would be the best way to append it to json?
I'm using 

`ioutil.WriteFile("big_marhsallz.json", j, os.ModePerm)`
and got this error 

 `cannot use j (type string) as type []byte in argument to iouti`

Comment: ok! just a reminder... we hardcoded the postition 7. if you get 10 items or more in the list you will have problems. instead of 7 you would need to use a formula (8 for 10-99 items, 9 for 100-999.....)

Comment: my solution is very simple - for this reason i only commented, didn't post it. if you are using marshall, you are in the right track, writing something more robust. in this case you wouldn't use my approach. take a look at https://gobyexample.com/json

Comment: @brunoff Thank you, what will be the best way to write data J that you wrote into JSON File?

Comment: Hmm, i seem to manage to write inside. using


`file, _ := json.MarshalIndent(j, "", " ")
 _ = ioutil.WriteFile("aaa.json", file, 0644)`

But the json file have
` "{ \"data\": { \"1\": \"8{0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0\"} }" `

Comment: I have answered with the more generic approach, better than the one I made on the comment. They both generate the same j. When you complained about `cannot use j (type string) as type []byte in argument to iouti`, the solution was wraping j around bytes in order to cast it []byte(j)

Answer (score 1):

Different approaches to solve to problem.

The simple (and safe) approach:

```
// import "fmt" "strings"
j := fmt.Sprintf(`{"data":{"1":%s}}`, strings.Join(strings.Fields(fmt.Sprintf("%d", results)), ","))
```

Previously in the comments I have made this lazier approach, without strings, but it is less safe:

```
// import "fmt"
j := fmt.Sprintf("%#v",*results); j = "{ \"data\": { \"1\": \""+j[7:len(j)-1]+"\"} }"
// works when the array size is between 1 and 9, above this, the "7" must increase
```

Now using the native golang json infrastructure.

Here, an example, using hard-coded `results := []uint{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}`

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
)
type d struct {
    Data o `json:"data"`
}
type o struct {
    One []uint `json:"1"`
}
func main() {
    results := []uint{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
    j, _ := json.Marshal(&d{Data:o{One:results}})
    err := ioutil.WriteFile("output.json", []byte(j), 0777) // i can't test here I don't know if []byte(j) or []byte(string(j)) should be used
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

But once your array is of uint8 instead of uint and golang's json encode []uint8 (which is the same as []byte) as base64 strings, we have to implement our own Marshaller to avoid this behaviour by implementing MarshalJSON, in the same way as seen on [How to marshal a byte/uint8 array as json array in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14177862/how-to-marshal-a-byte-uint8-array-as-json-array-in-go).

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "io/ioutil"
    "strings"
    "log"
    "fmt"
)
type d struct {
    Data o `json:"data"`
}
type o struct {
    One []uint8 `json:"1"`
}
func (t *o) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    var one string
    if t.One == nil {
        one = "null"
    } else {
        one = strings.Join(strings.Fields(fmt.Sprintf("%d", t.One)), ",")
    }
    jsonresult := fmt.Sprintf(`{"1":%s}`, one)
    return []byte(jsonresult), nil
}
func main() {
    results := []uint8{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
    j, _ := json.Marshal(&d{Data:o{One:results}})
    err := ioutil.WriteFile("output.json", []byte(j), 0777) // i can't test here I don't know if []byte(j) or []byte(string(j)) should be used
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. One last error i think...
`cannot use results (type []byte) as type []uint in field value`

I change the o struct to One []uint to []byte
and the string i write in json is always AAAAA.. instead of value

Comment: ok, to workaround this we have to implement our own marshaller. but once we are implementing our own marshaller, i believe it is better to use the simplier approach, without golang's native json support. i left all different solutions in the answer.

Comment: sorry to bother you again, is it possible to append to the json instead of overwriting it? do i have to redefined the struct array once again?

Answer (score 0):

I used to have the same problem, so I fixed it with below code:

```golang
// sample-entity.go
type Sample struct {
    sample int `db:"sample" json:"sample"`,
}
```

writing to json file

```golang
// it will create a new file if exists already too
jsonFile, jsonFileError := os.Create(directory + "/[file_name].json")
jsonToWrite := []Sample{
    {
         sample: 1
    }      
}

if jsonFileError != nil {
    panic(jsonFileError)
}
defer jsonFile.Close()

// write in json file
jsonWriter := json.NewEncoder(jsonFile)
jsonWriter.Encode(jsonFile)
```